# python subprocess.run ответ на вопрос в ходе исполнения y или n

Tags: python, subprocess

Пишу маленького бота для управления домашнего VPN на PiVPN столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
    list_files = subprocess.run(["pivpn", "-r", name_user_pc])
    print( list_files.returncode)
```

в ходе исполнения pivpn задает вопрос y или n и я должен ответить, не могу ни где найти нормальной информации как заставить Python ответить самостоятельно.

Comment: subprocess.communicate ?

Comment: subprocess.Popen, чтение из его stdout вопроса и запись в stdin ответа